# What type of USB flash disk can be used to boot externally

Tags: boot, usb, operating-systems, usb-storage, media-creation-tool

I have a Sandisk Cruzer Switch 8GB on which I have the win10 media creation tool. My computer is running windows 7 professional and I have the Gigabyte Dual Bios and MicroATX motherboard from Gigabyte. I have an intel core duo 2.0. So I attempt to boot from my external device. On startup, I hit F12 to enter that menu. None of them correspond to my USB (I tried them all they all startup normally), and I know that first of all my usb is somehow incompatible. I tried to install the media creation tool on it and it says this type of usb is incompatible. So I just copy it from a friend's usb (which is a fancy warship-shaped usb with no specifications at all from the back) and so when i try to boot from that it does not work.

Short question: What types of usb are compatible with installing OS on them?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but there really isn't any flash drives you can't do this with. You're likely running into issues with Legacy/CSM support versus UEFI. You just need to tinker with your BIOS boot settings

Comment: You reckon it's easier to just use an RW CD?

Comment: It might be slower to install but usually the most universally compatible if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the following solution after some search: SanDisk Cruzer Switches are a bit of a different architecture. So the computer reads them not as removable storage, but as an external hard-drive. That's why, the media creation tool will never detect them. After that I used any CD RW instead of my USB. By the way, some other USB's don't work as well, like [this one](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Toshiba-USB-Flash-Drive-8GB-/322500608310?hash=item4b1688c136%3Ag%3A-gQAAOSwWxNYuknW) which I can't find its model number.